# ¿Cúal tabla se lleva la llave Extranjera en una relacion (1,1)?

Tags: base-de-datos

tengo dos tablas una de farmaceutico y una de ciudad, la relación según un problema dado me llevo a ponerle una relacion 1 a 1, pero mi duda es la siguiente, ¿Cúal tabla se queda con la llave primaria de la otra?, o ¿Qué solución se puede encontrar?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La tablas simplemente tienen su id y el nombre respectivo(ciudad,farmaceutico)

Comment: eso depende, que dice el enunciado que tratas de resolver?, podrías mostrar la estructura de las tablas?

Comment: las preguntas que son tareas, deben incluir el mínimo intento, los errores obtenidos; por favor revisa [ask] pues es importante agregues lo que hayas tratado aunque sea muy mínimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A la pregunta que haces, la respuesta es la siguiente:
Siempre los modelos relaciones tienen que ser un reflejo de la realidad que se propone. Asi que yo te hago la siguiente pregunta:

Puede existir una ciudad sin farmacia?

La repuesta es que si.

Puede existir una farmacia sin ciudad?

La respuesta es que no.

**Por lo que primero tienes que crear una ciudad para que pueda existir una farmacia. Por lo tanto la `FOREING KEY` de la farmacia debe apuntar a la `PK` de la ciudad.**

Aqui te paso el Modelo Relacional, normalizado, como solo puede haber un farmaceutico por ciudad la clave primaria del farmaceutico es el id de la ciudad. El resto ya lo puedes ver, sino entiendes algo me lo dices.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
-- Generado por Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler 18.1.0.082.1035
--   en:        2018-09-09 20:08:18 CEST
--   sitio:      Oracle Database 11g
--   tipo:      Oracle Database 11g



CREATE TABLE accion_terapeutica (
    id_accion_terapeutica   NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    nombre                  VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)
);

ALTER TABLE accion_terapeutica ADD CONSTRAINT accion_terapeutica_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_accion_terapeutica );

ALTER TABLE accion_terapeutica ADD CONSTRAINT accion_terapeutica__un UNIQUE ( nombre );

CREATE TABLE cargo (
    id_cargo       NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    nombre_cargo   VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)
);

ALTER TABLE cargo ADD CONSTRAINT cargo_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_cargo );

ALTER TABLE cargo ADD CONSTRAINT cargo__un UNIQUE ( nombre_cargo );

CREATE TABLE ciudad (
    id_ciudad   NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    nombre      VARCHAR2(80 CHAR) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ciudad ADD CONSTRAINT ciudad_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_ciudad );

CREATE TABLE composion (
    id_composion   NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    nombre         VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)
);

ALTER TABLE composion ADD CONSTRAINT composion_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_composion );

ALTER TABLE composion ADD CONSTRAINT composion__un UNIQUE ( nombre );

CREATE TABLE empleado (
    id_empleado   NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    id_cargo      NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    nombre        VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)
);

ALTER TABLE empleado ADD CONSTRAINT empleado_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_empleado );

CREATE TABLE farmaceutico (
    id_ciudad   NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    nombre      VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)
);

ALTER TABLE farmaceutico ADD CONSTRAINT farmaceutico_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_ciudad );

CREATE TABLE farmacia (
    id          NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    id_ciudad   NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    nombre      VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)
);

ALTER TABLE farmacia ADD CONSTRAINT farmacia_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id );

CREATE TABLE farmacia_empleado (
    id_empleado   NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    id_farmacia   NUMBER(4) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE farmacia_empleado ADD CONSTRAINT farmacia_empleado_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_empleado,
                                                                                id_farmacia );

CREATE TABLE laboratorio (
    id_laboratorio   NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    nombre           VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)
);

ALTER TABLE laboratorio ADD CONSTRAINT laboratoio_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_laboratorio );

ALTER TABLE laboratorio ADD CONSTRAINT laboratoio__un UNIQUE ( nombre );

CREATE TABLE medicamento (
    id_medicamento          NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    id_composcion           NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    id_presentacion         NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    id_laboratorio          NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    id_accion_terapeutica   NUMBER(3) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE medicamento ADD CONSTRAINT medicamento_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_medicamento );

CREATE TABLE presentacion (
    id_presentacion   NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    nombre            VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)
);

ALTER TABLE presentacion ADD CONSTRAINT id_presentacion_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_presentacion );

ALTER TABLE presentacion ADD CONSTRAINT id_presentacion__un UNIQUE ( nombre );

CREATE TABLE stock (
    id_farmacia      NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    id_medicamento   NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    cantidad         NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    precio           NUMBER(6,2) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE stock ADD CONSTRAINT stock_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_farmacia,
                                                        id_medicamento );

ALTER TABLE empleado
    ADD CONSTRAINT empleado_cargo_fk FOREIGN KEY ( id_cargo )
        REFERENCES cargo ( id_cargo );

ALTER TABLE farmaceutico
    ADD CONSTRAINT farmaceutico_ciudad_fk FOREIGN KEY ( id_ciudad )
        REFERENCES ciudad ( id_ciudad )
            ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE farmacia
    ADD CONSTRAINT farmacia_ciudad_fk FOREIGN KEY ( id_ciudad )
        REFERENCES ciudad ( id_ciudad );

ALTER TABLE farmacia_empleado
    ADD CONSTRAINT farmacia_empleado_empleado_fk FOREIGN KEY ( id_empleado )
        REFERENCES empleado ( id_empleado );

ALTER TABLE farmacia_empleado
    ADD CONSTRAINT farmacia_empleado_farmacia_fk FOREIGN KEY ( id_farmacia )
        REFERENCES farmacia ( id );

ALTER TABLE medicamento
    ADD CONSTRAINT med_accion_terapeutica_fk FOREIGN KEY ( id_accion_terapeutica )
        REFERENCES accion_terapeutica ( id_accion_terapeutica );

ALTER TABLE medicamento
    ADD CONSTRAINT medicamento_composion_fk FOREIGN KEY ( id_composcion )
        REFERENCES composion ( id_composion );

ALTER TABLE medicamento
    ADD CONSTRAINT medicamento_id_presentacion_fk FOREIGN KEY ( id_presentacion )
        REFERENCES presentacion ( id_presentacion );

ALTER TABLE medicamento
    ADD CONSTRAINT medicamento_laboratoio_fk FOREIGN KEY ( id_laboratorio )
        REFERENCES laboratorio ( id_laboratorio );

ALTER TABLE stock
    ADD CONSTRAINT stock_farmacia_fk FOREIGN KEY ( id_farmacia )
        REFERENCES farmacia ( id );

ALTER TABLE stock
    ADD CONSTRAINT stock_medicamento_fk FOREIGN KEY ( id_medicamento )
        REFERENCES medicamento ( id_medicamento );



-- Informe de Resumen de Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler: 
-- 
-- CREATE TABLE                            12
-- CREATE INDEX                             0
-- ALTER TABLE                             28
-- CREATE VIEW                              0
-- ALTER VIEW                               0
-- CREATE PACKAGE                           0
-- CREATE PACKAGE BODY                      0
-- CREATE PROCEDURE                         0
-- CREATE FUNCTION                          0
-- CREATE TRIGGER                           0
-- ALTER TRIGGER                            0
-- CREATE COLLECTION TYPE                   0
-- CREATE STRUCTURED TYPE                   0
-- CREATE STRUCTURED TYPE BODY              0
-- CREATE CLUSTER                           0
-- CREATE CONTEXT                           0
-- CREATE DATABASE                          0
-- CREATE DIMENSION                         0
-- CREATE DIRECTORY                         0
-- CREATE DISK GROUP                        0
-- CREATE ROLE                              0
-- CREATE ROLLBACK SEGMENT                  0
-- CREATE SEQUENCE                          0
-- CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW                 0
-- CREATE SYNONYM                           0
-- CREATE TABLESPACE                        0
-- CREATE USER                              0
-- 
-- DROP TABLESPACE                          0
-- DROP DATABASE                            0
-- 
-- REDACTION POLICY                         0
-- 
-- ORDS DROP SCHEMA                         0
-- ORDS ENABLE SCHEMA                       0
-- ORDS ENABLE OBJECT                       0
-- 
-- ERRORS                                   0
-- WARNINGS                                 0
```

Un saludo.